# How can i handle arguments in c with getopt_long

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

i don't really understand how can i correctly handle command line arguments in c using getopt_long function, i create this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int next_option;
    /* String of short options */
    const char *short_options = "hl:k";
    /* The array of long options */
    const struct option long_options[] = {
        { "help",  0, NULL, 'h' },
        { "launch", 1, NULL, 'l' },
        { "kill",  0, NULL, 'k' },
        { NULL,    0, NULL, 0   } 
    };

    do {
        next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
        switch (next_option) {
            case 'h':
                /* User requested help */
                fprintf(stdout, "HELP\n");
                break;
            case 'l':
                fprintf(stdout, "launching\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Want to launch on port %s\n",\
                        optarg);
                break;
            case 'k':
                fprintf(stdout, "KILLING\n");
                break;
            case '?':
                /* The user specified an invalid option */
                fprintf(stdout, "Requested arg does not exist!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case -1:
                /* Done with options */
                break;

            default:
                /* Unexpected things */
                fprintf(stdout, "I can't handle this arg!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while(next_option != -1);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And the output is strange, cause we can pass garbage data as command line arguments and my program don't check this errors! How can i fix that.

An example of execution :

```
$ ./command_line -h garbage
HELP
$ ./command_line --help garbage
HELP
$ ./command_line --launch 1200 garbage
launching
Want to launch on port 1200
$ ./command_line --lBADARG 1200
command_line: unrecognized option `--lBADARG'
Requested arg does not exist!
$ ./command_line -lBADARG 1200
launching
Want to launch on port BADARG
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, what's happening is this:

in this case:

```
$ ./command_line --lBADARG 1200
command_line: unrecognized option `--lBADARG'
Requested arg does not exist!
```

by giving it `--lBADARG` you're saying look for the LONG argument `lBADARG`, and you don't have one.

in this case:

```
$ ./command_line -lBADARG 1200
launching
Want to launch on port BADARG
```

you're successfully telling it to use the `-l` flag which has an argument.  It behaves as expected, telling you that argument is `BADARG`.

If you try

```
$ ./command_line -l 1200
```

or

```
$ ./command_line -l1200
```

or

```
$ ./command_line --launch 1200
```

that should do what you expect.  And if you want to get the arguments that are *not* options, you'll find them in the argv vector *after* you've done the getopt processing, because getopt_long conveniently permutes the argv vector to leave non-option arguments there.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, i understand all this, my problem is how can i protect my program from bad arguments like this?

Comment: You don't. The beauty of `getopt` is that all programs using it exhibit the same argument behavior. It's silly to mess with that.

Comment: @funnyCoder, you do it the way you normally would -- once getopt gets the option argument (like "1200" in `-l 1200`) then you check if it's meaningful and correct.  getopt and its kin are option *parsers* -- they know the syntax, not the semantics.

Comment: @CharlieMartin, Thanks as you said i need to check if arguments are correct or not with some additional code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `garbage` is getting through okay is because `getopt` and its brethren are for processing *options,* not all command lne arguments. Not all arguments are options.

The reason that `--lBADARG` is treated differently to `-lBADARG` is because of the way it wants to handle them. `--lBADARG` is an option `lBADARG` with no parameters while `-lBADARG` is the `-l` option with a parameter of `BADARG`. The former is not listed as a valid option but the latter is.

And the final possible issue is that `BADARG` is being treated as a port. That's because the `getopt` stuff neither knows nor cares about parameter *types,* that's up to your code. If you want to ensure it's numeric, you should check for that. It may well be that you want to support symbolic port names (looked up in `/etc/ports` for example).

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo, so i assume that i need to check by my self command arguemnts? i can do that with a lot of if else loops and i don't need getopt_long at all! I was thinking that this function is able to do this stuff for me.

Comment: @funnyCoder, it won't do _everything_ for you but it really does take away some of the grunt work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i will try to handle args without getopt_long :).